# Anyway to stop Windows bringing app to front when displaying a context menu on tray icon?

Tags: windows, menu, trayicon

We are experiencing this annoying problem where we have a context menu on our tray icon, if we display this context menu we **have** to SetForegroundWindow and bring it to the front. This is really annoying and not at all what we want.

Is there a workaround, I notice that Outlook MS Messenger and other MS apps do not suffer this, perhaps they are not using a standard menu and have had to write their own ... why dont they release this code if they have?

This article describes the 'as design' behaviour: [Menus for Notification Icons Do Not Work Correctly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135788)

**EDIT**
We are using C++/Win32 not forms, so we use TrackPopupMenu.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ContextMenu or ContextMenuStrip?

Your saying that opening the ContextMenu on a trayicon focuses all app forms?

I have not experienced that, though I use the newer ContextMenuStrip class, not ContextMenu for my trayicons.

EDIT: Would be nice to know if you are using Windows.Forms or WIN32, or MFC or what.